# Stop counter when clicked on the button in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am created a simple counter that count from 1 to 10, Its works for me. But now I need to implement if someone want to stop the counter by clicking on the button then it should stop there and the text in the Button should also changed from

`<button @click="countToTen()">**Start counting**</button>`

to

`<button @click="countToTen()">**Stop counting**</button>`

This is in Vue js and I am very new to it. Have googled a lots and tried different options but no luck so far with it. Any Help Will be Appreciated !

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        welcomeMsg: 'Testing',
        result: 0,
      },

      methods: {
        countToTen() {
          console.log("I have been Clicked " + this.result)
         
          if (this.result < 10)
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.result += 1
              this.countToTen();
            }, 1000)

          if (this.result <= 0) {
            clearTimeout();
            return
          }
        },

      }
    })
  </script>
```

```
//displaying it here:
<button @click="countToTen()">Start counting</button>
    <p id="result">TimerStarted: {{result}}</p>
```

OutPut:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet:
You can create data properties `started` and `timeout` for holding setTimeout state.
Then You can switch buttons with `v-if` and `v-else`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    welcomeMsg: 'Testing',
    result: 0,
    started: false,
    timeout: null
  },

  methods: {
    countToTen() {
      this.started = true
      if (this.result < 10)
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.result += 1
          this.countToTen();
        }, 1000)
    },
    stopCountToTen() {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      this.started = false
      if(this.result === 10) this.result = 0
    }
  }
})
    
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="countToTen()" v-if="!started">Start counting</button>
  <button @click="stopCountToTen()" v-else>Stop counting</button>
  <p id="result">TimerStarted: {{result}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola for your response. Will try it on my code and will get back to you. Thanks again !